# Should I use a subquery or sum in this situation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I am trying to get line 11 (which can have multiple results of square footage numbers of different areas of a house such as porches, garages and includes living area) and subtract line 10 if possible to get the total square footage of areas in a house other than living area.

```
as a-- sum(id1.[calc_area] - pp.living_area) as [other_ area],
```

my problem is the two numbers are from different tables, and the `select` statement uses a different `from` table `pv`. What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

```
select distinct pv.prop_id,
pv.hood_cd as neighborhood,
pv.abs_subdv_cd as subdivision,
cast (pv.[legal_desc] as char(16)) as legal,
[deed_date],
[consideration],
pv.prop_val_yr as year,
sts1.[situs_num] as address,
cast(sts1.[situs_street] as char(11)) as street,
pp.living_area,
id1.[calc_area] as [total_area],
cast (pp.[land_total_acres]as decimal (6,2))as acres,
[sale_type],
case when [sale_date] >='01/01/2014'then convert(varchar(18), [sale_date], 101)else''end as'sale date',
pp.ls_table,
(pv.land_hstd_val + pv.land_non_hstd_val + pv.ag_market + pv.timber_market)as land_val,
cast(pp.[main_land_total_adj]as decimal (5,2)) as land_adj_total,
(pv.imprv_hstd_val + pv.imprv_non_hstd_val)as imprv_val,
case when [sale_date] >='01/01/2014'then [sale_price] else 0 end as'sale price',
pv.market
from property_val pv with (nolock)        
inner join prop_supp_assoc psa with (nolock) on
       pv.prop_id = psa.prop_id
       and pv.prop_val_yr = psa.owner_tax_yr
       and pv.sup_num = psa.sup_num
inner join property p with (nolock)on
       pv.prop_id = p.prop_id
inner join owner o with (nolock) on
       pv.prop_id = o.prop_id
       and pv.prop_val_yr = o.owner_tax_yr
       and pv.sup_num = o.sup_num
inner join account ac with (nolock) on
       o.owner_id = ac.acct_id
inner join property_profile pp with (nolock) on
      pv.prop_id = pp.prop_id
      and pv.prop_val_yr = pp.prop_val_yr
left outer join imprv_detail as id1 with (nolock) on
      pv.prop_id = id1.prop_id
      and pv.prop_val_yr =  id1.prop_val_yr 
      and pv.sup_num = id1.sup_num
left outer join
       (select cop.prop_id,
        convert(varchar(20), co.deed_dt, 101) as deed_date,
        co.consideration as consideration, s.sl_dt as sale_date,
        s.sl_price as sale_price, s.sl_type_cd as sale_type
              from chg_of_owner_prop_assoc cop with (nolock)
              inner join chg_of_owner co with (nolock) on
                     co.chg_of_owner_id = cop.chg_of_owner_id
              inner join sale s with (nolock) on
                     co.chg_of_owner_id = s.chg_of_owner_id
              where cop.seq_num = 0
              )as c
              on c.prop_id = pv.prop_id
```

basic results with some columns hidden-----

```
prop_id  address   street       living_area total_area acres
x        322       SURBER ST    939             48         0
x        322       SURBER ST    939            288         0
x        322       SURBER ST    939            939         0
xy       318       SURBER STRE  1202             0         0
xy       318       SURBER STRE  1202           120         0
xy       318       SURBER STRE  1202           340         0
xy       318       SURBER STRE  1202          1052         0
```

Comment: A SUM would be more performant on large tables, however, I would not want to write that group by with all of your fields. If the tables are relatively small then use your best judgement. You might want consider a subquery inside of your main.

Comment: Yep..."group by" is going to look like a book. I was hoping a short subquery would be smarter....but to be honest, I'm not sure how to make it work

Comment: Each table has about 40,000 rows.

Comment: Maybe a subtable ?

Comment: That or add as much as I try and avoid it you could put that subquery in the select clause.

Comment: you have complex query, when you asking about solution then you should simplify sql by skipping some tables and fields (if isn't important in question), good practice is add some example output

Comment: out put is exactly what i need---- except i get 3 or more lines per 'prop_id' in result as most prop_id have more than one calc_area. All other values are unique per pid except where already filtered by year, sup_num......i am not sure how to post a result sample on this site.......

Comment: put a editied sample of results- each pid should have a single results line.

Answer (score 0):

if you need only additional sum and all currently returned rows then use `SUM OVER` function:

```
sum(id1.[calc_area] - pp.living_area) over (PARTITION BY pv.prop_id, pv.prop_val_yr) as [other_ area]
```

you can modify partitioning, for example:

```
sum(id1.[calc_area] - pp.living_area) over (PARTITION BY pv.prop_id, pv.prop_val_yr, pp.ls_table) as [other_ area]
```

but if you have unwanted row multiplication when you join table and you need aggregated values from this table, then use subquery in `OUTER APPLY` clause (and don't join this table in other way), for example:

```
SELECT ...
, id1.total_area
...
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT Sum(calc_area) as total_area
  FROM imprv_detail
  WHERE prop_id = pv.prop_id = id1.
  and prop_val_yr = pv.prop_val_yr
  and sup_num = pv.sup_num
  ) AS id1
```

then to calculate `other_area` use `total_area - total_living_area`

Comment: Ls_table is a schedule that the property land value is based. All others have unique values per property id. Except for calc_area.  It will have a value for each area of a property such as porch, garage....etc.  to make it unique I need to sum it together. When comparing h ouse knowing how much living area and how much 'other' sq.ft is important. So it is the only one I need a sum for

Comment: Thanks ! I do appreciate the help.